# Expected identifier error in C

Tags: c, identifier

For some reason I am getting the error:

```
expected identifier or '(' before 'wordlist'
```

in my header file (as well as the corresponding function definitions) for the two functions returning `wordlist` pointers.

With the following code:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

typedef struct word{
   char *string;
   struct word* next;
}word;

typedef struct wordlist{
   word *head;
   word *tail;
}wordlist;

*wordlist populateList(FILE *file);

*wordlist encrypt(wordlist *wl, int rotation);

void toFile(wordlist *wl, char *outputFileName);

#endif
```

Can anyone tell me why this might be?

Comment: The standard formatting for C is deceiving.  Typically you see `someType *someVar;` for a declaration, which makes it less obvious that the type of `someVar` is `someType*`.  I prefer to write `someType* someVar;` to make the association clearer, and, incidentally, make one less likely to erroneously code `*someType` for a return type in a method declaration.

Comment: @HotLicks - it's a bit of a toss-up, really.  Writing `someType* someVar, someVar2` makes it easy to assume that `someVar2` is of type `someType *` when it's actually just `someType`.  I find `someType *someVar, *someVar2` much nicer for that reason.

Comment: Another rule is to never use `type var1, var2...`.  There are far too many pitfalls there, and it's functionally unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you declare a pointer, the asterisk must follow the type name, not precede it:

```
wordlist * populateList(FILE *file);
//       ^
//       |
//      Here
```

Answer (score 0):

If in `populateList` and `encrypt` you want to return a pointer to `wordlist`, the correct syntax is `wordlist *`, not `*wordlist` (it's exactly as it is everywhere else).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define or declare a variable you specify the type of the variable followed by the variable name.  So if you want a variable of type `wordlist` you would use:

```
wordlist myVariable;
```

If you want to specify a variable to be a pointer to a variable type, you prefix the variable name with an asterisk so if you want a variable that is a pointer to a variable of type `wordlist` you would use:

```
wordlist *myVariable;
```

The reason why most experienced C programmers put the asterisk with the variable name is because of something like the following:

```
wordlist myVariable, *pVariable1, myVariable2, *pVariable2;
```

The above will create four variables.  `myVariable` is of type `wordlist`. `myVariable2` is of type `wordlist`.  `pVariable1` and `pVariable2` are of type pointer to `wordlist`.

So the asterisk acts as a kind of adjective or qualifier or modifier for the variable name declaration indicating that the variable is not of the type specified but is instead a pointer to the type specified.

The combined variable definition is the same as the following four lines of definitions.

```
wordlist myVariable;  // declares a variable of type wordlist
wordlist *pVariable1; // declares a pointer to a variable of type wordlist
wordlist myVariable2; // declares a variable of type wordlist
wordlist *pVariable2;  // declares a pointer to a variable of type wordlist
```

Function definitions/declarations work similarly.

```
wordlist *myFunc (void) {
    wordlist *myNew = malloc (sizeof(wordlist));

    if (myNew) {
        // set up myNew stuff
    }

    return myNew;
}
```

**Edit: function pointers**

You can also specify a variable that contains a function pointer.  For instance for myFunc() above you might specify something like the following.  Notice that I am using parenthesis to enforce a specific order of evaluation.  What this says is that pFunc is a pointer to a function that does not accept arguments (void argument list) and which returns a pointer to a wordlist variable.  There are rules about operator and modifier precedence in C however as expressions become more complicated, it is usually better to enforce an evaluation order using parenthesis.  See [Programs as Data: Function Pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html)

```
wordlist *((*pFunc) (void)) = myFunc;   // pointer to a function that returns a pointer to a wordlist
```